# Spring security doesn't work in Spring 4 with Spring boot

Tags: spring, security

My entity is as below:

User Class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Column(unique=true)
private String name;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String password;

@Transient
private String matchingPassword;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Email
@Column(unique=true)
//@ValidEmail
private String email;

private boolean enabled;
```

Role class:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
public static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String role;

private String username;
```

The WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/register",     "/registeruser").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/upload").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .usernameParameter("name").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws    Exception {
      //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
       auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("select name, password, enabled from user where name=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from role where username=?");
}
```

}

POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I logged in as an "ROLE_USER" user, I can still access the "/upload" web page. Don't know what's the cause. Any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try executing the query ? does it return something?

Comment: yes. "SELECT NAME, PASSWORD, enabled FROM USER WHERE NAME='asdf'" return {"asdf", "asdf", b'1'} , and SELECT username, role FROM role WHERE username='asdf' return {"asdf", "ROLE_USER"}